# Reload function Caph-list (Tizen - Samsung TV)

Tags: jquery, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I am facing a problem trying to use the  reload function of the caph-list (Tizen - Samsung TV). I have created a very simple example to explain my problem based on the caph3 documentation.
Unfortunately the caph-list is not loading the new items, Is it some sintax error?

```
var item = ["itemA","itemA","itemA","itemA","itemA","itemA","itemA","itemA","itemA"];

$('document').ready(function(){

  $('#list1').caphList({
    items: item,
    template: 'template1',
    containerClass: 'container'
  });
  setTimeout(delayFunction,4000)

});

var delayFunction = function(){
  item = ["itemB","itemB","itemB","itemB","itemB"];
  $('#list1')[0].caphList.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$("#category_0").caphList({
            items: items,
            template: "playList",
            containerClass: "list-container",
            wrapperClass: "list-scroll-wrapper"
        }).on("focused", function($event) {
            .....
        }).on('selected', function($event){
             .......
        });
$("#category_0")[0].caphList.reload();
```

You should call caphList twice. On initialisation and before refresh.
Unfortunately i didn't find this in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#list1').trigger('reload');`